# Nginx redirection configuration

Tags: nginx

How can i achieve a redirect from https://example.com:5656 to https://www.example.com nginx. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the nginx reverse proxy. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

It would look like this in your case:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com:5656/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```